# How to write any text in the others orientation

Tags: positioning

How to turn text orientation in the four diferent positions?

[image]

Any text.

Comment: Don’t forget to accept the answer (tick the green ‘V’ at the left side of the answer).

Comment: No, tick the _grey_ ‘V’ (actually it’s a hook). It should turn into a green one … :-)

Comment: Besides accepting @GonzaloMedina's answer, it would be nice if your [blog post](http://latexbr.blogspot.com.br/2012/08/texto-refletivo-espelhado-no-latex.html#more) also attributed the solution to him.

Answer (score 21):

You can do this with `\scalebox` from the `graphicx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\LaTeX\scalebox{-1}[1]{\LaTeX}

\scalebox{1}[-1]{\LaTeX}\scalebox{-1}[-1]{\LaTeX}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`TikZ` is another option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) {\LaTeX};
\node[xscale=-1,right=of a] (b) {\LaTeX};
\node[yscale=-1,below=of a] (c) {\LaTeX};
\node[xscale=-1,yscale=-1,right=of c]{\LaTeX};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And `PSTricks` offers `\psscalebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\noindent\LaTeX\psscalebox{-1 1}{\LaTeX}\\
\psscalebox{1 -1}{\LaTeX}\psscalebox{-1 -1}{\LaTeX}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @RegisdaSilva You're welcome!